# Object.hasOwnProperty() yields the ESLint 'no-prototype-builtins' error: how to fix?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using the following logic to get the i18n string of the given key.

```
export function i18n(key) {
  if (entries.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return entries[key];
  } else if (typeof (Canadarm) !== 'undefined') {
    try {
      throw Error();
    } catch (e) {
      Canadarm.error(entries['dataBuildI18nString'] + key, e);
    }
  }
  return entries[key];
}
```

I am using ESLint in my project. I am getting the following error:

> Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object.
>   It is a '*no-prototype-builtins*' error.

How do I change my code to resolve this error ? I don't want to disable this rule.

Comment: You should probably read the docs. There are examples of *correct* code ~ http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Comment: The code is working fine. This is a linting error. I just want to modify the syntax so that the linting rule is satisfied.

Comment: @passion That will stringify `entries`, ignore `key`, and check if `Object` has a property with that string.

Comment: @Phil Stackoverflow *is* the docs for many.

Answer (score 467):

You can access it via `Object.prototype`:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
```

That should be safer, because

- Not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`
- Even for objects which inherit from `Object.prototype`, the `hasOwnProperty` method could be shadowed by something else.

Of course, the code above assumes that

- The global `Object` has not been shadowed or redefined
- The native `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` has not been redefined
- No `call` own property has been added to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`
- The native `Function.prototype.call` has not been redefined

If any of these does not hold, attempting to code in a safer way, you could have broken your code!

Another approach which does not need `call` would be

```
!!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
```

Comment: You save my day, i have to refactor old code from my friend and have to replace so many line of code

Comment: If you're going to be cautious enough to use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` then it would definitely be preferable to use an explicit cast with `Boolean()`.

Comment: @limeandcoconut Using `!!` is more cautious than `Boolean()` since the former cannot be overwritten

Comment: I suppose that's true, but I'm not concerned with the fact that `Boolean` could be theoretically overridden. The much greater trade off imo is the loss of specificity, and maintainability. I'm firmly in the camp that the things like `!!` are harder to read, less specific, and easier to accidentally mess up during a later edit than doing an explicit cast.

Answer (score 54):

For your specific case, the following examples shall work:

```
if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(entries, "key")) {
    //rest of the code
}
```

OR

```
if(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(entries, key)) {
    //rest of the code
}
```

OR

```
if({}.propertyIsEnumerable.call(entries, "key")) {
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: The last example(propertyIsEnumerable) works for me thanks

Answer (score 43):

You can use `Object.hasOwn(obj, prop)` instead. [hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is intended to be a replacement for `Object.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: This is the way to go in 2022. It has good browser support, is shorter and easier to remember than the accepted answer, and solves the problem ESLint is complaining about. MDN says, `Note: Object.hasOwn() is intended as a replacement for Object.hasOwnProperty().`

See https://tomdn.com?object.hasOwn.

Comment: I see that hasOwn() is supposed to work, but it doesn't seem to be supported in Node v18.10.0.

Answer (score 20):

It seems like this would also work:

`key in entries`

since that will return a boolean on whether or not the key exists inside the object?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` checks if a string or symbol is an own property. `key in entries` checks if it's an own or inherited one.

Answer (score 14):

@Orial answer is correct

Use this:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, "objectProperty");
```

Comment: oof. that is not elegant....

Comment: @Shayne write elegant please )

Comment: No Im not saying the post is inelegant, just the API is inelegant lol

Comment: @Shayne ah got it, yes agree, it's bit uncomfortable )

Answer (score 2):

To make code more elegant it can be in form a polyfill:

```js
if (!Object.hasOwn) {
    Object.prototype.hasOwn = function (object, property) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property);
    }
}

console.log(Object.hasOwn({test: 1}, 'test'), Object.hasOwn({tes: 1}, 'test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is  working  for  me   so  try  with  it

```
let  bug={
 name:"test"
   }
if (bug && typeof bug === 'object' && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(bug, name)) {
```

}

Comment: ok, I do  that thank you for telling me

Answer (score 0):

> Object.hasOwn() is officially replacement for
> Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty().
>
> if this objects has it's own property then it returns true.if property
> does not exist or inherited then it returns false.so hasOwn() static
> method and hasOwnProperty() method behaves in a same way.

```
const object1 = {
  prop: 'exists',
};

console.log(Object.hasOwn(object1, 'prop')); //true.
```

**your code will be**

```
export function i18n(key) {
  if (Object.hasOwn(entries,key)) {
    return entries[key];
  } else if (typeof (Canadarm) !== 'undefined') {
    try {
      throw Error();
    } catch (e) {
      Canadarm.error(entries['dataBuildI18nString'] + key, e);
    }
  }
  return entries[key];
}
```