# Fixing "Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object" error

Tags: hasownproperty

Based on `hasOwnProperty()` method [docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) I wrote the following:

```
const myObj = {
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2'
}

if (!myObj.hasOwnProperty('prop3')) {
  myObj.prop3 = 'val3'
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target
> object

Why does it not work if it's the same as in the docs, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the Object.prototype method in the following logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282873/how-do-i-access-the-object-prototype-method-in-the-following-logic)

Comment: Thanks :) Using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)` did the job yes. But that doesn't explain why ESlint refuses a code copied straight from MDN docs

Comment: ESLint can be configured in many ways and I'd be careful having the mindset that, "if it's in MDN docs, it's the only way to do it".  Documentation can get stale or be opinionated.  Take the info and do what's best for you and your project :D

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you :)

Comment: This answer explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283005/247696

Answer (score 3):

Use the static `Object.hasOwn()` instead:

```js
const myObj = {
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2'
}

if (!Object.hasOwn(myObj, 'prop3')) {
  myObj.prop3 = 'val3'
}

console.log(Object.keys(myObj)); //returns [ 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3' ]
console.log(myObj.prop3); //returns val3
```

`Object.hasOwn()` is intended as replacement for `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` [HasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

Comment: hasOwn doesn't exist on type ...