# Caveats of using the nullish coalescing operator (??) to check for the existence of a key in an object?

Tags: javascript, nullish-coalescing

With the nullish coalescing operator (`??`), one is tempted to use it for specifying defaults for non-existent object keys, as suggested in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003999/how-to-get-value-from-object-with-default-value), e.g.:

```
let a = foo.bar ?? 'default';
```

However, it's alternatives in this case (mainly `in` and `hasOwnProperty`) have their caveats and risks. Calling `<key> in <object>` matches keys in an object's prototype chain, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript). Calling `<object>.hasOwnProperty(<key>)` won't work, for example, if the object's `hasOwnProperty` is shadowed, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282873/how-do-i-access-the-object-prototype-method-in-the-following-logic). Surely, `??` has its own gotchas to watch out for.

What are the pitfalls with `??` compared to the other methods of checking for an existence of a key in any object?

---

In other words, are the risks of doing the following:

```
let a = foo.bar ?? 'default';
```

Closer to this

```
let a = 'bar' in foo ? foo.bar : 'default';
```

Or this

```
let a = foo.hasOwnProperty('bar') ? foo.bar : 'default';
```

Or this

```
let a = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'bar') ? foo.bar : 'default';
```

Or are they different from either?

Comment: `??` is not purposed to check the existence, it's purposed to check a value.

Comment: If `foo` is undefined then `a = foo.bar ?? 'default'` will throw an error

Comment: If you're unsure of `hasOwnProperty`, you can do `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'prop');`, that method is less likely overridden. That provides `obj` to exist, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risks you are talking about are irrelevant when you know what kind of object to expect, in your particular case one with a `bar` property. There is no `Object.prototype.bar`.

The "risks" of using `??` after a property access are exactly the same as the risks of doing the property access. Your statement `let a = foo.bar ?? 'default';` is equivalent to

```
let a = foo.bar == null ? 'default' : foo.bar;
```

or (without accessing the property twice)

```
let a = foo.bar;
if (a == null) a = 'default';
```